# Create divs pattern as it mentioned inside

Tags: html, css

i've been trying to create pattern for my website using div elements. The problem is than my knowledge in css is very limited and i've no idea how to make the pattern like this [image]

I tryed to use block, inline-block, but were not able to achieve the pattern i'm targeting to.
It's possible to do it with table, but than code looks like piece of thing.

It would be great if you will help me, because doing this not only to create a web site but also to learn css, so comments are really welcome.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

make a parent div and add all properties to that like width of the container and height of the container. then add css property to each element individually or by grouping in class